# 'xinput list' shows same device twice & device IDs change: how to use 'set-prop' in a script?

Tags: usb, logitech, xinput

For some reason Logitech's USB receiver shows up twice in `xinput list` device list:

```
Logitech USB Receiver         id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]
Logitech USB Receiver         id=14 [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

When I try to `xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Receiver" "someSetting" n`, I of course get:

> Warning: There are multiple devices matching 'Logitech USB Receiver'.
>   To ensure the correct one is selected, please use the device ID, or prefix the
>   device name with 'pointer:' or 'keyboard:' as appropriate.
>
> unable to find device Logitech USB Receiver

The prefix doesn't help as it is the same device (pointer).

I can use the ID instead, but **the problem** is that the ID of course changes between startups, so I can't makes this automatic (simple script that on startup sets sensitivies for all my pointing decvices).

So, is it possible to remove the duplicate device, make `xinput` ignore it or still refer to the device by it's name? If neither of these are possible, then I guess a script would have figure out the IDs (and from those, it seems to be always the smaller one).

The commands I want to use are:

```
xinput set-prop n "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2.4
xinput set-prop n "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Someone else had a same problem, and someone provided a script solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756948

Comment: short answer:  `xinput list --id-only pointer:'name of the mouse'`

Comment: I still get `Warning: There are multiple devices matching 'pointer:XYZ Mouse'`

Comment: @ki9 This is probably because your mouse registers multiple xinput pointing devices to support additional functionalities, for instance to remap keys, or to configure chroma effects, or to expose dedicated API, just like my Razer does.  
I have created [a gist that contains a bash script](https://gist.github.com/mierzejk/c71d9c110a74844a41906337d22caff6#file-setting-xinput-properties-of-pointing-devices-having-indistinct-names-md) that identifies the correct xinput `id` based on the device name, and banking on the `udev`'s `bInterfaceNumber` / `ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM` value being constant.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, new answer.

After struggling a little bit (the other answers didn't help me) I just solved a duplicated device problem with my Logitech M325 mouse.

The problem was happening because I was using the [Logitech Unifying Receiver](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/mice/unifying-receiver-usb.910-005235.html) and I had added my old Logitech M325 mouse to it (using [solaar](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar)) a while ago.

**In short: if you're using the Logitech Unifying Receiver), please check if there are two devices with the same name registered and then remove the unused one.**

Answer (score 0):

If you grapple with duplicate xinput names, then perhaps you will want to check out the following gist that includes a bash script to determine the correct `id` by exploiting the device's constant `bInterfaceNumber` values: [Setting xinput properties of pointing devices having indistinct names](https://gist.github.com/mierzejk/c71d9c110a74844a41906337d22caff6).